# How to run Datomic transactor as a Windows service?

Tags: windows, service, datomic

How would I go about running Datomic transactor as a Windows service? Preferably using free tools, such as Apache Commons Daemon.

Does anyone have actual experience of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else is pondering on this: It is quite easy to use https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw to run a batch script (here the datomic start script) as a windows service, having the cmd.exe as the executable and the path to the script as a parameter.